# Calculating the average area of the states listed in states.txt

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting

Need someone to calculate the average area, in square miles, of the states listed in `states.txt`.

`States.txt` (file):

```
State           Population   SqMi      Region 
------------------------------------------
California           39.37   163.7       West
Texas                29.36   268.6      South
Florida              21.73    65.7      South
New_York             19.33    54.7  NorthEast
Pennsylvania         12.78    46.1  NorthEast
Illinois             12.59    57.9    Midwest
Ohio                 11.69    44.8    Midwest
Georgia              10.71    59.4      South
North_Carolina       10.60    53.8      South
Michigan             9.97    96.7    Midwest
```

Output should look like this:

```
Average Area: 82.85 square miles
```

Note my awk program will be ran like this:

```bsh
awk –f <file.awk> states.txt
```

Comment: Anything you have tried yet?

Comment: been trying various things that dont work what so ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
BEGIN {sum=0} {sum+=$3} END {print "Average Area: "sum/(NR-2)" square miles"}
```

First two lines can be ignored as the sum operation will count strings as zero value

Comment: i get syntax errors using this but ill keep trying

Comment: @JimmyGonzalez, my mistake, wrong bracket. Corrected :)

Comment: had to edit syntax alittle thank you it works